# I can't run the program it says "<terminated> satorreProgram2main(1)[Java Application]"

Tags: java, swing

**MAIN**

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class satorreProgram2main{

public static void main(String[]args){
    satorreProgram2sub satorre = new satorreProgram2sub();
    satorre.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    satorre.setSize(200,150);
    satorre.setVisible(true);
    satorre.setResizable(false);
  }
}
```

**SUB**

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;

import java.awt.event.*;

import java.util.*;

import java.text.*;

public class satorreProgram2sub extends JInternalFrame {

private JLabel aznarl1, aznarl2, aznarl3;
private JTextField aznart1, aznart2, aznart3;
private JButton aznarb1, aznarb2;
private JPanel aznarp1;
private Handler aznarh1;

public satorreProgram2sub(){
    super("Date AZNAR",true,true,true,true);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    aznarp1 = new JPanel();

    aznarl1 = new JLabel("Date 1:         ");
    aznarl2 = new JLabel("Date 2:         ");
    aznarl3 = new JLabel("Difference: ");

    Date aznartoday = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat aznarformat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

    aznart1 = new JTextField(7);
    aznart1.setText(""+ aznarformat.format(aznartoday));
    aznart1.setEditable(false);

    aznart2 = new JTextField("",7);

    aznart3 = new JTextField(7);
    aznart3.setEditable(false);

    aznarb1 = new JButton("Compute");
    aznarh1 = new Handler();
    aznarb1.addActionListener(aznarh1);

    aznarb2 = new JButton("Exit");
    aznarh1 = new Handler();
    aznarb2.addActionListener(aznarh1);

    aznarp1.add(aznarl1);
    aznarp1.add(aznart1);
    aznarp1.add(aznarl2);
    aznarp1.add(aznart2);
    aznarp1.add(aznarl3);
    aznarp1.add(aznart3);
    aznarp1.add(aznarb1);
    aznarp1.add(aznarb2);

    add(aznarp1);

}
private class Handler implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Compute")){
            Date aznartoday = new Date();
            String aznarnewdate = aznart2.getText();

            SimpleDateFormat aznarformat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
            Date aznarconvertedate = null;
            try {
                aznarconvertedate = aznarformat.parse(aznarnewdate);
            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            long diff = aznartoday.getTime() - aznarconvertedate.getTime();

            aznart3.setText(" "+ Math.abs(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))+" day(s)");

        }else if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Exit")){
            System.exit(0);
        } 
    } 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please take the [tour], learn [ask], then go through the [help] and how to make a [mcve], then come back and [edit] your question accordingly, otherwise it will be closed because it's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: Please paste stacktrace or logs for problem areas why jvm terminated

Answer (score 1):

Check the [Oracle tutoria](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html)l firstly.

> Usually, you add internal frames to a desktop pane. The desktop pane, in turn, might be used as the content pane of a JFrame.

Apparently, you are using `JInternalFrame` as the bottom container and it's improper.

The `<terminated>` here doesn't indicate there is error but mean your application has already completed.

You can modify you main class like below:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.*;

public class satorreProgram2main{

    public static void main(String[]args){
        satorreProgram2sub satorre = new satorreProgram2sub();
        satorre.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        satorre.setSize(200,150);
        satorre.setVisible(true);
        satorre.setResizable(false);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JDesktopPane desktop = new JDesktopPane();
        desktop.add(satorre);
        frame.setContentPane(desktop);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```